# Compare String columns in Pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas

So I have a pandas DataFrame and I want to compare the strings in both columns if they are shorter than one another. This is what I have so far:

```
data['Description v DescNormal'] = data[data['DescNormal'].str.len() < data['Description'].str.len()]
```

However this fails. I want to assign this to obtain a new column which indicates True or False accordingly.

Comment: I think you just need that: `data['Description v DescNormal'] = data['DescNormal'].str.len() < data['Description'].str.len()`. Because for your case you using subset of `data`.

Comment: please add samples of dataframe data

Answer (score 0):

```
data['Description v DescNormal'] = data['DescNormal'].str.len() < data['Description'].str.len()
```

this should work for you